# FASTCGI process has failed frequently recently. Try the request again in a while

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, fastcgi, iis-10

We have setup a Wordpress Website on IIS 10 which was working fine. But suddenly it stops working and i got this error

> "FASTCGI process has failed frequently recently. Try the request again
>   in a while"

Restarting IIS fixed this problem.

Anybody tell me why this issue has occurred and how we can fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in your PHP error logs around the time that it's happening?

Comment: Nothing in logs

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365 It is a very good question for PHP experts, but not with IIS. You should also notice that old releases like PHP 5.6 are obsolete, and upgrading to 7.x might help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command prompt as administrator and navigate to the php-cgi.exe
   folder.
2. Execute any PHP file from your application to know the exact error. In my case, I created a simple phpinfo.php page and executed
   following command.

   **C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4.5>php-cgi.exe E:\Websites\mysite\phpinfo.php**
3. It showed me the exact error saying 'vcruntime140.dll is not
   compatible with this PHP build' & I have updated to **'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019'**. You can download it from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2019).
4. Once you identified and resolved the error(point 3), you need to restart IIS server and run your website. It will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP 8 turn track_errors Off in php.ini . Track_errors have been deprecated since 7.2 and can cause a fatal error in IIS

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the solution to the issue, It is due to the low value given to "Rapid Fails PerMinute" - see above image posted by German Martin.

From Microsoft's website the default value for "Rapid Fails PerMinute" is 90 but i reduced it 10 and then the error "FASTCGI process has failed frequently recently...." started showing up.

Once i set it back to the default value of 90 , the error stopped. This is what worked for me, in my case.

Answer (score -1):

You need to maximize "Instance MaxRequest" at FASTCGI Configuration. Just clic en IIS root -> FastCGI Settings, select you php-cgi.exe for WP and clic Edit. Then increise Instance MaxRequests

[image: a busy cat]
[IIS FastCGI Settings]

Comment: This did not work for me.